# Getting simple if/else condition to work upon submit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, form-submit

I have tried many different things including adding              `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));` to autoload.php, among other things.

When I fill out a value for first name and last name and nothing else and press submit, it just redirects back to the same page (not to clientRegistrationSuccess.php) as specified in the `if{} else{}`

**Form (View)**

```
 echo validation_errors();

       echo form_open('index/pages/clientcreation',$CustCreationFormAttr);
        echo form_label('First Name: ','fname');
            echo form_input($CustCreationFirstName);echo '<br>';
        echo form_label('Last Name: ','lname');
            echo form_input($CustCreationLastName);echo '<br>';
        echo form_label('Title: ', 'title');
            echo form_input($CustCreationClientTitle);echo '<br>';
        echo form_label('Company: ', 'co');
            echo form_input($CustCreationCompany);echo '<br>';
        echo form_label('Email: ','email');
            echo form_input($CustCreationEmail);echo '<br>';
            echo form_submit($CustCreationSubmit,'Submit');
```

**Controller**

```
class Clientcreation extends CI_Controller
    {   
        function index(){
            ####################################
            $this->load->view('navigation');
            $this->load->view('pages/clientcreation');
            $this->load->view('footer');   

            ####################################
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library( array('form_validation') );

            ## Set Validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required');

            ## Perform Validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('pages/clientcreation');
            }
        else{
                $this->load->view('pages/success/clientRegistrationSuccess');
        }
        } 

    }
```

Additionally, the form is loading as intended... like:
[image: img1]

The paths match up too, because if I change `$this->load->view('pages/clientcreation');` to `$this->load->view('pages/hi');` it is calling this view. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So, what's the problem? View not found? Where are the form vars created? (I don't see where and how you pass them to the view)

Comment: The problem is, it doesnt show errors if i dont put in anything and just press [enter]

Comment: Because you're not echoing errors anywhere...put an 'echo validation_errors()' in your view, for example

Comment: This is included at the top of the view : echo validation_errors(); (please see above updated code).

Comment: @DamienPirsy - thanks for trying to help, you twisting my thinking to realize the obvious. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part.

The reason the validation wasn't working is, I was trying to output the validation errors directly in my view, when I should have been outputting on the controller, like:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
             echo validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('pages/clientcreation');
        }
```

on the controller end, NOT on the view.
 (at the top)

Comment: Glad you solved, but I must say that echoing in controller is not the right procedure, and outputting in the view is what you should do (and I assure you it works, as I've done it countless times). Anyway, if this works for you...

Comment: I wondered why if I added the echo validation_errors() to the controller and not in the view though why nothing happens ?